# How to define ArrayField to django forms

Tags: python, django

How to define ArrayField in django form

I have some function params for which I want to add validation so I created a form and one of the function parameter is list. How can I define that in forms

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class SampleParams(forms.Form):
    num = forms.IntegerField()
    li = ArrayField(forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False))
```

but I think ArrayField is related when I want to store data in database but my case is just to validate the params but not store data

Comment: What do you actually want to have in the form? What data do you want to validate and how should it be entered?

Comment: just want to have some Integer, String and array data, so i could define IntegerField, CharFied but not ArrayField in form (form is not related to any model)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.forms import SimpleArrayField
li = SimpleArrayField(forms.CharField(max_length=100))
```