# How can I let the user add a new field in a Django-form dynamically, instead of letting them append the entire form at every addition?

Tags: django, django-forms, htmx

In **forms.py**:

```
class BillGateway(forms.Form):
    from_date=forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), label='From ', label_suffix=' - ')
    to_date=forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), label='To ', label_suffix=' - ')
    billing_date=forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), label='Date of Billing ', label_suffix=' - ')
    rt_cash_amount_desc=forms.CharField(label='RT Cash Amount Description', label_suffix=' - ', required=False)
    rt_cash_amount=forms.DecimalField(label='RT Cash Amount', label_suffix=' - ', required=False)
    other_desc=forms.CharField(label='Other Head', label_suffix=' - ', required=False)
    other_amount=forms.DecimalField(label="Other Head's Amount", label_suffix=' - ', required=False)
```

In **views.py**:

```
def bill_gateway_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fro=request.POST.get('from_date')
        to=request.POST.get('to_date')
        bill_date=request.POST.get('billing_date')
        rt_cash_desc=request.POST.get('rt_cash_amount_desc')
        rt_cash_amount=request.POST.get('rt_cash_amount')
        other_desc=request.POST.get('other_desc')
        other_amount=request.POST.get('other_amount')
        request.session['fro']=fro
        request.session['to']=to
        request.session['bill_date']=bill_date
        request.session['rt_cash_desc']=rt_cash_desc
        request.session['rt_cash_amount']=rt_cash_amount
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/provisional_bill/')
    else:
        form=BillGateway()
        return render(request, 'account/bill_gateway.html', {'form':form})
```

In **templates**:

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" id="savebtn">Proceed</button>
    </form>
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to let the user add more of the `other` fields, both, the `other_desc` and `other_amount` if he/she needs to fill in more details in the bills.

I'm fairly new to this concept. I have seen some tutorials in which the tutors mainly used htmx to achieve such things and seemed pretty cool and easy but what they did was adding the whole form again upon clicking the add button. I just want the user to be able to add these two fields only and not the entire form. How can I achieve this? I have spent my whole day looking for a suitable solution on the internet but have failed to do so. Is there a way to do so using htmx itself? Or something else which might help me get through? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you need to give user the ability to update these 2 fields (other_desk,other amount)   to achieve this you can use update class view from django or create your own view  in both cases you need to include only these 2 fields in the update form ,if you gonna to create your own biew then you need to pass id number of bill gateway object as an argument to view function or its slug if slug field is available

Comment: No, actually I want the user to be able to add more of these two fields in the form if he wishes to. Sorry if was not clear enough in my post.

Comment: Then you just need to change these two fields to array feilds see this link 
  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/

Comment: But I don't need to save those data, I just need them to pass their values to another function via session and render them subsequently to a bill.

Comment: then try using SimpleArrayfield, check this link     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218408/how-to-define-arrayfield-to-django-forms

Comment: This still doesn't give full idea as to how it works. I mean, will the user be able to add more fields to the form if he/she requires? I don't think so. Please let me know how this is the solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Its not matter of adding more fields!! its matter of adding more values to the same filed......Arrayfield is just an array of fields, so let us say if user wants to add  more than one "other_amount" values then he just need to separate them by comma like any other array, you can add help text to inform user about this feature...

Comment: Okay, I get the idea. But how might I use it in `other_desc` which is a `Charfield` and it might naturally contain a comma? May I ask the user to separate the values by semi colon or something?

Comment: Just explain to user in help text to include "other_desc" in single or double qoutation mark separated by commo, if you find my reply helpful then please vote up!!