# Django form data loop

Tags: django, forms

How can I loop through form data where the ending part could be 1,2,3,4 and so on, and store in the DB without hardcoding the DB like below so each description would be on its own line but one person could post description1-10 and the other 10-27 and so on

for example instead of say this

```
order.description_1 = request.POST.get('description1')
order.length_1 = request.POST.get('length1')
order.width_1 = request.POST.get('width1')
order.depth_1 = request.POST.get('depth1')
order.weight_1 = request.POST.get('weight1')
order.description_2 = request.POST.get('description2')
order.length_2 = request.POST.get('length2')
order.width_2 = request.POST.get('width2')
order.depth_2 = request.POST.get('depth2')
order.weight_2 = request.POST.get('weight2')
```

currently the form passes request.POST.get('description1') and with a limit of request.POST.get('description5') but would like each description on its own row and not be subject to a hardlimit and uses a bit of javascript to append the x value to the name. The postdata form is also hardcoded so not using forms.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request.POST` is a python dictionary, so you can loop through it like this:

```py
for key, value in request.POST.items():
    print(key, value)
    # set the property for order
    # you can work on key and change it if need
    setattr(order, key, value)
```

For a better implementation of this requirement, you can use django forms with `ArrayField` fields:

[django simple array field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/#simplearrayfield)

[how-to-define-arrayfield-to-django-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218408/how-to-define-arrayfield-to-django-forms)